gpg keys with restricted encryption
I'm trying to understand why on my system gpg keys are restricted. I generated new gpg key using gpg --expert --full-gen-key command, and then I added authentication and signing keys (I selected only Authentication and only Signing options). But they are shown with R flag, e.g.
sec   rsa4096 2024-05-15 [SC]
...
ssb   rsa4096 2024-05-15 [E]
ssb   rsa4096 2024-05-15 [AR]
ssb   rsa4096 2024-05-15 [SEAR]

My question is why they carry R flag (restricted), and why I don't see just [A] key? And, what is this restriction means.
